# tty doesn't list ttyUSB0 so arduino doesn't list serial ports

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, upload

Okay so lsusb gives 
Bus 002 Device 019: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter

dmesg|grep 'ttyUSB' gives

[63723.589107] usb 2-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0

but tty lists only /dev/pts/0 although in /dev there is a ttyUSB0 file (or whatever it is because vim says its not a file)

I can use cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 9600 and transmit to arduino nano as the rx LED blinks. On starting arduino I get the "java.lang.NullPointerException thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver" error.

System: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa (64 bit)

Comment: `tty` tells you the terminal device that your current terminal session is connected to. Nothing to do with listing what terminal devices are available.

Comment: You are assuming a problem with serial ports. That is unlikely to be the case. Your real problem is something to do with the Arduino IDE's programming. What version of the IDE are you using and how did you install it?

Comment: I agree with Majenko and also don't believe it has anything to do with your ports. The exceptions you mentioned look like there is something wrong with your environment, maybe updating the arduino IDE or java itself will help. You could also check if the problem persists when using an older version of the IDE

Comment: To be sure that has nothing to do with the ports/serial communication, I suggest reading out the atmega with avrdude manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I was using the software center to get arduino IDE and that didn't work well. Downloading the official IDE from arduino.cc worked without hassle. Lesson learnt: Not all linux distros have package repos as up-to-date as Arch. :P